# snaplet-environment always returning fallback

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

i have a config similar to:

```
app
{
 environments
 {
   production
   {
    config-url = "http://www.google.com"
   }
 }
}
```

and i'm starting my app like

> myapp @production

however,

> lookupEnvDefault "config-url" "http://www.microsoft.com"

always returns "http://www.microsoft.com"

if i edit the file and take out the *production* entry then i get the following error:

> Given env name: @production wasn't found in your config file.

so it's clearly parsing the config file properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WTF.  The way I got this to work?

```
app
{
 environments
 {
   production
   {
    config-url = ""
   }
 }
}
environments
{
  production
  {
   config-url = "http://www.google.com"
  }
}
```

trace outputs

> http://www.google.com

if i leave off the app node and descendants or even just the app/environments/production/config-url node then it's unable to find the environment, ie it outputs the following error

> Given env name: @production wasn't found in your config file.

this has got to be a bug

update: i submitted this patch https://github.com/statichippo/Snaplet-Environments/tree/patch-1

Answer (score 0):

Your middle-layer namespace needs to be `environments` and not `environment`.

Comment: i'm sorry, i mistyped that on SO.  it is environments, i've edited the post.  as i mentioned, if i take out the production environment or just specify myapp @foobar then i get an error about env name not found so obviously it's parsing...